# open a div on specific position with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've created 2 divs, second div opens on hover inside the first div but i incresed the postion of the second div to double of first one and in one box i've such 8 divs so i want that all the 2nd divs open in to the boxes body so how i can set the postion of the div which is placed at bottom to be open bottom to top that mean it do should not cross the body of the boxes

**My Code:**

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <div class="boxes">
     <div class="box1">
      <div class="box_onhov">
        this div will be appear on hovering the box1 and its double in size of box1
      </div>
     </div>
     <div class="box2">
      <div class="box_onhov">
       this div will be appear on hovering the box1 and its double in size of box1
     </div>
        .
        .
        .
        .
     <div class="box8">
      <div class="box_onhov">
       this div will be appear on hovering the box1 and its double in size of box1
      </div>
     </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The boxes are adjusted 4 in one row so when hovers on first div the div_onhov covers it and the div at bottom of it so when hover on bottom div means on div 5 so it should not cross the body and must display bottom to top. same as the 4th div should not be displyed to the right it must display inside the outer div to the left.

Comment: please post some CSS and JS code.

Answer (score 0):

this can help you just make your animation width or height

```
$('.box1').hover(function(){
  $(".box_onhov").toggle(function(){
  $(.box_onhov).animate({height:40},200);
  },function(){
  $(.box_onhov).animate({height:0},200);
  });
});
```